# Monitoring Alert for Cloud Build failure on master

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-build

I would like to receive a notification on my Notification Channel every time in Cloud Build a Build on `master` fails.

Now there were mentions of using Log Viewer but it seems like there is no immediate way of accessing the branch.

Is there another way where I can create a Monitoring Alert/a Metric which is specific to `master`?

Answer (score 3):

A easy solution might be to define a logging metric and link an alerting trigger to this.

1. Configure Slack alerting in [Notification channels](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting) of GCP.
2. Define your logging metric trigger in [Logs-based Metrics](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting/notifications). Make a Counter with Units 1 and filter using the logging query language:

   ```
   resource.type="build"
   severity=ERROR
   ```

   or

   ```
   resource.type="build"
   textPayload=~"^ERROR:"
   ```

   [image]
3. Create an [Alerting Policy](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting/policies/create) with that metric you've just defined and link the trigger to your Slack notification channel you've configured in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

you can create Cloud Build notifications sending you updates to desired channels, such as [Slack](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-notifications/configure-slack) or your [SMTP](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-notifications/configure-smtp) server [HTTP](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-notifications/configure-http) channel. Also [create a PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/subscribe-build-notifications) topic when your build's state changes, such as when your build is created, when your build transitions to a working state.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the pain of trying to get the official GCP slack integration via Cloud Run working.  It was too cumbersome and didn't let me customize what I wanted.

Best solution I see is to get Cloud Build setup to send Pub/Sub messages to the cloud-builds topic.  With that, you can use the below repo I just made public to filter on the specific branch you want but looking at the data_json['substitutions']['BRANCH_NAME'] field.

https://github.com/Ucnt/gcp-cloud-build-slack-notifier

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to receive information about Cloud Build failure logs in Slack.

The contents of the attached link [1] have been organized and uploaded on Github, so please refer to the Github link [2] below for more details.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-notifications/configure-slack?hl=en

[2] https://github.com/JangGyeongSik/gcp-cloudbuild-notification